# How to create formset with initial data that will show formset.has_changed() is False?

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.10.

Learning formsets. Namely **has_changed()** method.
Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet.total_error_count

In case of get request my example shows me always that the formset has changed. Later we'll check it in post request. But so far just newly created formset.

Well, I can't create a new formset that will show that it has not changed. 
In other words, a newly created formset at once shows that it has changed.

Please, have a look at the html that is produced. I copied keys for initial data from there.

The example in documentation is not demonstrative. But my own example doesn't work as expected.

The problem is with form[0] in the formset. In other words, form[0].has_changed = True.

By the way! This will show formset.has_changed = False:

```
initial_data = [{'form-0-title': '', 'form-0-pub_date': ''}]
```

But what about real initial data? In case of forms there were some initial data: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/forms/api/#checking-which-form-data-has-changed

No, empty forms is not our method.

Could you help me.

**views.py**

```
class General(View):
    initial_data = [{'title': 'Initial title 0', 'pub_date': '2015-01-01'},     
                    {'title': 'Initial title 1', 'pub_date': '2016-01-01'}]
    ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=2, max_num=3) 

    def get_formset(self):

        data = {
                'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '3',
                'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '2',
                "form-MIN_NUM_FORMS": '0',
                "form-MAX_NUM_FORMS": '3',
                'form-0-title': self.initial_data[0].get('title'),                
                'form-1-title': self.initial_data[1].get('title'),
                'form-0-pub_date': self.initial_data[0].get('pub_date'),                
                'form-1-pub_date': self.initial_data[1].get('pub_date'),
                'form-2-title': "",
                'form-2-pub_date': "" 
                }

        formset = self.ArticleFormSet(
                                    data=data, 
                                    initial=self.initial_data
        )
        self.has_changed = formset.has_changed() # For debugging.

        return formset

    def get_context_data(self):        
        context = {'formset': self.get_formset()}
        return context

    def get(self, request):
        template_name = "general/article.html"
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    pub_date = forms.DateField()
```

**article.html**

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
    <h2>{{ forloop.counter0 }}</h2>
            <table>
                {{ form.as_table }}
            </table>
    {% endfor %}
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<h2>Formset changed?</h2>
<p>{{ formset.has_changed }}</p>

<h2>form[0] changed?</h2>
<p>{{ formset.0.has_changed }}</p>

<h2>form[1] changed?</h2>
<p>{{ formset.1.has_changed }}</p>
```

**html**

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='vWQq0Yl5gbVe7x1iKFX7uLCUlAL3RpBnQAQGIsRt7pwuJeqU7VDl3OE544Wt2oSN' />
    <input id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3" /><input id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2" /><input id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="3" />

    <h2>0</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th><label for="id_form-0-title">Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-title" name="form-0-title" type="text" value="Initial title 0" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-0-pub_date" name="form-0-pub_date" type="text" value="2015-01-01" /></td></tr>
            </table>

    <h2>1</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th><label for="id_form-1-title">Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-title" name="form-1-title" type="text" value="Initial title 1" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-1-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-1-pub_date" name="form-1-pub_date" type="text" value="2016-01-01" /></td></tr>
            </table>

    <h2>2</h2>
            <table>
                <tr><th><label for="id_form-2-title">Title:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-2-title" name="form-2-title" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_form-2-pub_date">Pub date:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-2-pub_date" name="form-2-pub_date" type="text" /></td></tr>
            </table>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<h2>Formset changed?</h2>
<p>True</p>

<h2>form[0] changed?</h2>
<p>True</p>


<h2>form[1] changed?</h2>
<p>True</p>
```

Comment: I suspect your problem is the date field. The initial data will have that as a datetime, but the posted data will be a string. That said, I really can't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: No, I have removed date field completely. The result has not changed. What I'm trying to do: learning. Just walking through the documentation. What troubles me is <input id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" /> Can't the problem be here? I set "id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS": '''. But there is no value attribute in the rendered html.

Comment: Why did you set `id_form...` instead of `form...` as with the other items?

Comment: I have noticed it. Changed. No success so far. I'll edit the post in a while.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, you seem to be right. I edited the post again. If I change DateField to CharField, the example is working as expected. I don't know how to validate DateField yet. Will be experimenting. But that seems to be quite another question. If you transform your comment into an answer, I'll gladly accept it. By the way, maybe you know how to cope with DateDield in this case?